# Show that $\int(\liminf f_n)\leq\liminf\int f_n.$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that $f_n\geq-g$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $g$ is a non-negative integrable function. Show that $$\int(\liminf f_n)\leq\liminf\int f_n.$$

My attempt:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $-f_n\leq g$; so $\int -f_n\leq\int g$, therefore $-f_n$ is integrable and hence $f_n$ is integrable. Now $(f_n+g)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of non-negative integrable functions. By Fatou's lemma $$\int(\liminf f_n)+\int g\leq\int\liminf(f_n+g)\leq\liminf\int (f_n+g)\leq\liminf\int f_n+\int g$$ or rather $$\int(\liminf f_n) \leq\liminf\int f_n$$.

Is the above argument correct? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to show integrability to apply Fatou's lemma (in this case it comes for free but it's not a necessary hypothesis). $g$ is supposed integrable in order to simplify $\int g$ on both sides at the end. A part from this, I think your proof is correct.

Comment: In fact, $f_n$ will in general not be integrable (take $f_n=1/n 1_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $g=0$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven You are right, $\int g\geq-\int f$ is not enough to imply integrability of $f$. I've been sloppy saying it comes for free. Thanks for pointing this out.